# Regex match the unknown characters with dash between

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm struggling with the following combination of characters that I'm trying to parse:

I have two types of text:

```
1. AF-B-W23F4-USLAMC-X99-JLK
2. LS-V-A23DF-SDLL--X22-LSM
```

I want to get the last two combination of characters devided by - within dash.

From the 1. `X99-JLK` and from the 2. `X22-LSM`

I accomplished the 2. with the following regex `'--(.*-.*)'`

How can I parse the 1. sample and is there any option to parse it at one time with something like OR operator?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `--(.*-.*)` that you tried matches the second example because it contains `--` and it matches the first occurrence.

Then it matches until the end of the string and backtracks to find another hyphen.

As `.*` can match any character (also `-`) and there are no anchors or boundaries set, this is a very broad match.

---

If there have to be 2 dashes, you can match the first one, and use a capture group for the part with the second one using a negated character class `[^-]`

The character class can also match a newline. If you don't want to match a newline you can use `[^-\r\n]` or also not matching spaces `[^-\s]` (as there are none in the example data)

```
-([^-]+-[^-]+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `-` Match `-`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^-]+-[^-]+` Match the second dash between chars other than `-`
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OAr7At/1)

For example using Javascript:

```js
const regex = /-([^-]+-[^-]+)$/;
[
  "AF-B-W23F4-USLAMC-X99-JLK",
  "LS-V-A23DF-SDLL--X22-LSM"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
})
```

Comment: Now I'm trying to get the USLAMC and SDLL, which goes after 3rd dash. I think I'm missing something ((

Comment: @vladpoverin If you want to cross more than one dash, and you would allow empty strings in between `-([^-]+)[^-]*-+[^-]*-+[^-]*$` https://regex101.com/r/owqwnE/1 You could also use a quantifier that repeats parts of 1 or more dashes `-([^-\n]+)(?:[^-\n]*-+){2}[^-\n]*$` See https://regex101.com/r/rhRnNx/1 and then change the value of the quantifier like `{2}` or `{3}`

Comment: Oh I think I got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can try lookahead to match the last pair before the new line. JavaScript example:

```js
const str = `
  AF-B-W23F4-USLAMC-X99-JLK
  LS-V-A23DF-SDLL--X22-LSM
`;

const re = /[^-]*-[^-]*(?=\n)/g;

console.log(str.match(re));
```